# Was it only the cases involving a death sentence that required two or three witnesses in Numbers 35 and deutoronomy 17?

Tags: law, numbers, deuteronomy, moses

Numbers 35 NASB

> [30]'If anyone kills a person, the murderer shall be put to death at the evidence of witnesses, but no person shall be put to death on the testimony of one witness.

Deuteronomy 17:6-7 NASB

> [6]On the evidence of two witnesses or three witnesses, he who is to die shall be put to death; he shall not be put to death on the evidence of one witness.
>   [7]The hand of the witnesses shall be first against him to put him to death, and afterward the hand of all the people. So you shall purge the evil from your midst.

In the above texts it seems only the cases involving a death sentence warranted that there be two or three witnesses

Was it standard procedure the issue of two or three witnesses or it only applied where a death sentence was involved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the two scriptures which deal specifically with this question, namely :

> At the mouth of two witnesses, or at the mouth of three witnesses, shall the matter be stablished, (Deuteronomy 19:15),

and . . .

> In the mouth of two or three witnesses shall every word be established, (II Corinthians 13:1),

I think that it is all (notable) matters - not just matters involving a death sentence - that are in need of proper attestation by more than just the hearsay of a single individual.